# OSGI bundle dependencies

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, bndtools, maven-bundle-plugin

I have created an bundle which relies on SLF4J and as such am using Logback for the OSGI implementation. This all bundles up and installs OK but when I come to start the bundle I get the following exception:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.felix.test
>   [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [com.felix.test [20](R 20.0)]
>   osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=groovy.lang) Unresolved
>   requirements: [[com.felix.test [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=groovy.lang)]

I can see in my manifest file `groovy.lang` is listed in `Import-Package` and I'm pretty sure the problem is that Logback is being embedded but none of it's references are.

I'm using to create the bundle, here's the config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
                *
            </Import-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>
                *
            </Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Directory>
                osgi-inf/libs
            </Embed-Directory>
            <Embed-Transitive>
                true
            </Embed-Transitive>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here's my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1436982944102
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_45
Built-By: tim.clifford
Bundle-ClassPath: .,osgi-inf/libs/org.osgi.core-1.0.0.jar,osgi-inf/libs/
 servlet-api-2.5.jar,osgi-inf/libs/org.apache.felix.scr.annotations-1.9.
 6.jar,osgi-inf/libs/httpclient-osgi-4.5.jar,osgi-inf/libs/httpclient-4.
 5.jar,osgi-inf/libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar,osgi-inf/libs/commons-logging-1.
 2.jar,osgi-inf/libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar,osgi-inf/libs/httpmime-4.5.ja
 r,osgi-inf/libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.jar,osgi-inf/libs/fluent-hc-4.5.ja
 r,osgi-inf/libs/ehcache-2.10.0.jar,osgi-inf/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar,os
 gi-inf/libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar,osgi-inf/libs/logback-classic-1.1.3.j
 ar,osgi-inf/libs/logback-core-1.1.3.jar
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.felix.test
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.felix.test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Embed-Dependency: *
Embed-Directory: osgi-inf/libs
Embed-Transitive: true
Embedded-Artifacts: osgi-inf/libs/org.osgi.core-1.0.0.jar;g="org.apache.
 felix";a="org.osgi.core";v="1.0.0",osgi-inf/libs/servlet-api-2.5.jar;g=
 "javax.servlet";a="servlet-api";v="2.5",osgi-inf/libs/org.apache.felix.
 scr.annotations-1.9.6.jar;g="org.apache.felix";a="org.apache.felix.scr.
 annotations";v="1.9.6",osgi-inf/libs/httpclient-osgi-4.5.jar;g="org.apa
 che.httpcomponents";a="httpclient-osgi";v="4.5",osgi-inf/libs/httpclien
 t-4.5.jar;g="org.apache.httpcomponents";a="httpclient";v="4.5",osgi-inf
 /libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar;g="org.apache.httpcomponents";a="httpcore";v="
 4.4.1",osgi-inf/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar;g="commons-logging";a="com
 mons-logging";v="1.2",osgi-inf/libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar;g="commons-co
 dec";a="commons-codec";v="1.9",osgi-inf/libs/httpmime-4.5.jar;g="org.ap
 ache.httpcomponents";a="httpmime";v="4.5",osgi-inf/libs/httpclient-cach
 e-4.5.jar;g="org.apache.httpcomponents";a="httpclient-cache";v="4.5",os
 gi-inf/libs/fluent-hc-4.5.jar;g="org.apache.httpcomponents";a="fluent-h
 c";v="4.5",osgi-inf/libs/ehcache-2.10.0.jar;g="net.sf.ehcache";a="ehcac
 he";v="2.10.0",osgi-inf/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;g="org.slf4j";a="slf4j
 -api";v="1.7.7",osgi-inf/libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;g="org.apache.commo
 ns";a="commons-lang3";v="3.4",osgi-inf/libs/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar;g
 ="ch.qos.logback";a="logback-classic";v="1.1.3",osgi-inf/libs/logback-c
 ore-1.1.3.jar;g="ch.qos.logback";a="logback-core";v="1.1.3"
Export-Package: com.felix.test;version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: groovy.lang,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.jms,jav
 ax.mail,javax.mail.internet,javax.management,javax.management.openmbean
 ,javax.naming,javax.naming.directory,javax.naming.ldap,javax.net,javax.
 net.ssl,javax.security.auth.x500,javax.sql,javax.swing.event,javax.tran
 saction,javax.transaction.xa,javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,jav
 ax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.stream.events,net.spy.memcach
 ed,org.apache.avalon.framework.logger,org.apache.felix.scrplugin,org.ap
 ache.felix.scrplugin.annotations,org.apache.felix.scrplugin.description
 ,org.apache.log,org.apache.log4j,org.codehaus.commons.compiler,org.code
 haus.groovy.control,org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers,org.codehau
 s.groovy.reflection,org.codehaus.groovy.runtime,org.codehaus.groovy.run
 time.callsite,org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling,org.codehaus.gro
 ovy.runtime.wrappers,org.codehaus.groovy.transform,org.codehaus.janino,
 org.hibernate,org.hibernate.cache,org.hibernate.cache.access,org.hibern
 ate.cfg,org.hibernate.impl,org.hibernate.stat,org.hibernate.transaction
 ,org.ietf.jgss,org.osgi.service.cm,org.quartz,org.quartz.impl,org.quart
 z.impl.jdbcjobstore,org.quartz.impl.matchers,org.quartz.simpl,org.terra
 cotta.quartz,org.terracotta.toolkit,org.terracotta.toolkit.atomic,org.t
 erracotta.toolkit.builder,org.terracotta.toolkit.cache,org.terracotta.t
 oolkit.cluster,org.terracotta.toolkit.collections,org.terracotta.toolki
 t.concurrent.locks,org.terracotta.toolkit.config,org.terracotta.toolkit
 .events,org.terracotta.toolkit.feature,org.terracotta.toolkit.internal,
 org.terracotta.toolkit.internal.cache,org.terracotta.toolkit.internal.c
 luster,org.terracotta.toolkit.internal.collections,org.terracotta.toolk
 it.internal.concurrent.locks,org.terracotta.toolkit.internal.feature,or
 g.terracotta.toolkit.monitoring,org.terracotta.toolkit.nonstop,org.terr
 acotta.toolkit.rejoin,org.terracotta.toolkit.search,org.terracotta.tool
 kit.search.attribute,org.terracotta.toolkit.store,org.xml.sax,org.xml.s
 ax.helpers,sun.misc,sun.reflect
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
Tool: Bnd-2.4.1.201501161923
```

Am I going about it the right way or is there a better method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your question "am I going about is the right way", the answer is "definitely not"!

**Please, please don't use `Embed-Dependency`**. This simply takes all of the transitive dependency graph (which in your case includes the Groovy language runtime, somehow) and sticks it inside your bundle.

This misses the point of OSGi entirely. Worse, when you develop your next bundle you will have to go through all this again! Eventually you will have tens of bundles, each carrying around a massive, dead weight of embedded dependencies.

As Christian said, stick to the defaults provided by the `maven-bundle-plugin`. You don't even need to specify `<Import-Package>*</Import-Package>` since this is already the default. As a result you will get a bundle that has package imports, which is a good thing! But you need to install bundles that provide exports that will match your imports.

Comment: Could you remove jpm4j website, because right now this site is trying to suggest to install some browser plugin.

Comment: @EvgenyKiselev Thanks for notification. Seems like the jpm4j domain expired and was taken over by spammers.

Answer (score 4):

You should not embed all dependencies into your bundle. Instead just run with maven bundle plugin defaults. It should create a bundle that you can then deploy into an OSGi container.

I am most experienced with [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/). There you can just install the bundle using:

```
install -s mvn:groupId/artifactId/version
```

In your case this might already work as Apache Karaf comes with pax-logging pre installed.

If you want to use plain felix it is a little more complicated as you will have to gather all dependencies and create a suitable start configuration. In that case [bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

From the exception you reported in your question I would say none of the bundles in your osgi environment is currently exporting the `groovy.lang` package. 
I would suggest to install the felix gogo shell in your runtime and to issue the following command in the osgi console:

```
g! inspect cap osgi.wiring.package
```

This will give you the list of all exported packages in your osgi instance: in this way you can verify whether or not the `groovy.lang` package is indeed missing.

If this is the case, then you should wrap the [groovy-all jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) in a bundle as explained [here](https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools/wiki/How-to-Wrap-Bundles) and include it in your running osgi bundles. If you want, you can search a ready-to-use osgi bundle for groovy-all in [jpm4j](https://jpm4j.org) website.

Comment: Surely the better answer is to not wrap the entire transitive dependency graph in a single bundle?!?